# Flutter Constructor showing error without @

Tags: flutter, dart

Here, I am trying to make a model class but strange it is showing error.
Here is the screen shot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTF6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ykqN.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0n4q.jpg)

The error is as it says when I hover my mouse onto this.text:
The parameter 'text' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Why do I need required? I mean , i did model class previously but I did not need to add required key word. I did the same thing opening a new project but the same error shows up.

The following in the code snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget{


  final String text;
  final double Size;
  final Color color;
  final FontWeight weight;

  CustomText({this.text, this.Size, this.color, this.weight});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }






}
```

Comment: yes , i know...but model class does not need required keyword. i created model class before without required keyword.

Comment: Because in StatelessWidget you should init the data if you using final.
Then you should not using final if the model doesn't required to filled with value

Comment: you shoud read https://dart.dev/null-safety then

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ykqN.jpg- see in this image,even if i remove the word stateless, the same problems persists

Comment: yes , the problem is solved.Thank you....Is it a new issue in fulltter

Comment: It is not an issue, that's how the programming language works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Flutter 2.0 (null safety) version released, you need to declare nullable (by adding ?), So here in your case you are declaring optional which
means it can be null, So either you need to make it a nullable value or add required keyword. like this

```
import 'package:material/material.dart'; 


class TempModel {
  final String? title; // either declare nullable
  final String subtitle; // either use required keyword
  final int? id;
  
  const TempModel({this.title, required this.subtitle, this.id});
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I got solution.